# Why the graph rendering is not displayed well in chrome?

Tags: jqplot

i have a problem with the rendering of my graph but just in Chrome (with edge and firefox it works) . I have the series of my graph that are my hourly shift (Example: 0-7, 13-14) but i noticed that in the past they were displayed well, while with the last version og google chorme this series are represented in thsi way:
0-   13-
7    14

do you know what i can check?
Thanks

Comment: sorry but the series was not writen well. Example i have 0- and in the row below i have 13 but i need to have all in the same row

Comment: please show us the code for the graph, html, css, any JavaScript that you use to generate the graph.

Comment: I actually understand why you might not want to take the time to put in the code. you're hoping for someone to say Yes I know, in jqplot version X for the latest chrome this bug exists because of Y so do this, without having to go through all the effort that would otherwise be required. Unfortunately that is not how StackOverflow works at all.